# Bcrypt password_compat PHP library

Tags: php, bcrypt

https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

I'm implementing bcrypt to my website using the library above. As stated in the description, the password_verify() can be used to check if a password corresponds to a specific hash. Is this what I'm supposed to use when users are loggning in? To take what they typed in for password and compare it with the hash in the database?

Question number two, where does salting come in? Don't I need to store a salt in the database for each user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `password_verify` is the function you use to verify a plaintext password against its hashed version.

Salting is already part of the process, the resulting hash contains a random salt. You do not need to do this manually.

It's indeed as simple as:

```
$registeredPassword = 'password';
$hashedPassword     = password_hash($registeredPassword);
// store $hashedPassword in database...

$enteredPassword = 'password';
if (password_verify($enteredPassword, $hashedPassword)) {
    // login successful
}
```

The `password_hash` implementation takes care of secure salting and hashing. Be sure to read the manual with its examples and notes: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php, http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php